# Re-using datasets in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I have a user object with property 1, property 2, and property 3.  I have a separate function to edit each property.  Therefore, I'll need to test each edit property function.  So I'll create 3 different expected datasets for the tests of successful property edits.  However, what if I end up adding a 4th property down the line?  Won't this force me to now add this property/value to all of the other datasets?  Should I just create 1 template dataset file, and then extract the data from the file and use a php array dataset?  This way, if I add a new property, I won't have to modify all of the previous datasets?

Concrete example:

Let's say I want to test that my edit email function works properly, and only changes the email.  My setup fixture would be:

setup-fixture.xml:

```
<dataset>
    <table name="users">
        <column>id</column>
        <column>email</column>
        <column>password</column>
        <row>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>user1@email.com</value>
            <value>password</value>
        </row>
    </table>
</dataset>
```

And my expected dataset would be:

edit-email-expected-dataset.xml:

```
<dataset>
    <table name="users">
        <column>id</column>
        <column>email</column>
        <column>password</column>
        <row>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>user1-changed-his-email@email.com</value>
            <value>password</value>
        </row>
    </table>
</dataset>
```

However, if I later added another property called "notes" to this user object, my setup fixture would now be:
new-setup-fixture.xml:

```
<dataset>
    <table name="users">
        <column>id</column>
        <column>email</column>
        <column>password</column>
        <column>notes</column>
        <row>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>user1@email.com</value>
            <value>password</value>
            <value>notes</value>
        </row>
    </table>
</dataset>
```

Therefore, I would also have to amend my expected dataset file in the edit e-mail function test to include this new "notes" property.

edit-email-expected-dataset.xml:

```
<dataset>
    <table name="users">
        <column>id</column>
        <column>email</column>
        <column>password</column>
        <column>notes</column>
        <row>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>user1-changed-his-email@email.com</value>
            <value>password</value>
            <value>notes</value>
        </row>
    </table>
</dataset>
```

My question is, how do I avoid having to edit all my expected datasets everytime I add an extra field?

Comment: Does property 1 or 2 affect property 3's result? How about in any other order? With Unit Tests you should really only be testing small portions of code any way. When you add a new property you should be adding new tests entirely to make sure that doesn't break the rest. Make sense?

Comment: To add to that, you can have a setup function or function that creates some Object for you that each of the unit tests can call.

Comment: Property 1 and 2 do not affect property 3's result, and the order does not matter either.  My issue is that I'm testing against a database, so if I add a new property in the setup fixture, I'll now have to add it to all of my expected dataset files as well.

Comment: Well you should be adding a test for each of the properties and whether or not they get affected by the edit function. You're correct that you don't want to have to add a new test for every single item when you add a new property. Do you have an example that might help illustrate what you're doing?

Comment: Ok so I have a setup fixture for this user object, which contains default values of 'hello world' for property 1, 2, and 3.  To test the edit function for property 1, I have an expected dataset with the value of 'goodbye' for property 1, and a value of 'hello world' for property 2 and 3.  I then create similar expected datasets for properties 2 and 3.  If I later decide to create a property 4, I will now have to modify the setup fixture as well as all the expected datasets for properties 1-3 to include this new property 4, right?

Comment: A concrete example would go a long way to helping us provide alternative solutions. In the meantime, check out [test fixtures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture).

Comment: Keep in mind, for backward compatibility, your code should likely allow this new database value to not be returned, so the old code continues to work correctly.  As such, your old tests should still pass without the extra field.  New tests can then be written to test with the new property and its influence/impact to your code.

Comment: @DavidHarkness, I've added a concrete example.

Comment: @StevenScott, if I exclude the new database value, won't I assume the risk that the function i'm testing may inadvertently affect the value of the new database value?

Comment: The old code will not use this until you change the code to reference it, so it would not change it for your test.  You could check it remains unchanged, but your older code never knew to change the value, and never returned it, so it would still not return the value or change it.  Once the old code is made aware of this value, then you need to update your tests for it.